# while deploying this code error still i didnt got the correct solution

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com, developer-console

```
trigger quotepotential on Quote_Line_Item__c (after insert,after update) {
    Set<id> uniqueNames=new Set<id>();
    for(Quote_Line_Item__c a :Trigger.new) {
        if(a.IsFutureContext__c) {
            a.IsFutureContext__c = false;
        } else {
            uniqueNames.add(a.id);
        }
    }
    if(!uniqueNames.isEmpty())
        asyncApex.processAccounts(uniqueNames);
}
```

Future class

```
global class asyncApex {
    @future
    public static void processAccounts(set<id> id) {
        Set<Id> quoteIds = new Set<Id>();
        List<Quote__c> quotes = new List<Quote__c>();
        for (Quote_line_item__c a : [Select Id, Name, IsFutureContext__c From Quote_line_item__c where ID IN :ID]) {
            a.IsFutureContext__c = true;
            if (a.Quote1__c != null){
                quoteIds.add(a.Quote1__c);
            }
            Map<Id, Quote__c> mapQuote = new Map<Id, Quote__c>([Select Id, Potential__c from Quote__c where Id in :quoteIds]);
            for(AggregateResult ar:[SELECT Quote1__c , SUM(Max_Batch__c)sumMax FROM Quote_Line_Item__c WHERE Quote1__c IN :quoteIds GROUP BY Quote1__c]) {
                if(mapQuote.containsKey((ID)ar.get('Quote1__c'))){
            Quote__C qu = mapQuote.get((ID)ar.get('Quote1__c'));
                    qu.Potential__c=(Decimal)ar.get('sumMax');
                    quotes.add(qu);
                }
            }
            if(quotes.isempty() == false)
            {
                update quotes;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: this is exception i am getting while deploying]

Comment: use debug logs and use system.debug to find of the reason which part of code not working.

Comment: you don't find any error by seeing the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your trigger is completely wrong; you shouldn't be using a field for this at all. Not to mention, Trigger.new is read-only in "after" triggers, so this code won't actually stop the recursive future calls. Try this trigger:

```
trigger quotepotential on Quote_Line_Item__c (after insert, after update) {
    if(System.isFuture()) {
        return;
    }
    asyncApex.processAccounts(Trigger.newMap.keySet());
}
```

Next, your aggregate query is incorrect-- when you do not alias a field, the expression is named 'exprX', where X is the numeric position of this expression. Change that portion as follows:

```
global class asyncApex {
    @future public static void processAccounts(Set<Id> quoteIds) {
        Map<Id, Quote__c> quotes = new Map<Id, Quote__c>();
        for(Id quoteId: quoteIds) {
            quotes.put(quoteId, new Quote__c(Id=quoteId, Potential__c=0.0));
        }
        for(AggregateResult ar:[SELECT Quote1__c Id, SUM(Max_Batch__c) sumMax FROM Quote_Line_Item__c WHERE Quote1__c IN :quoteIds GROUP BY Quote1__c]) {
            quotes.get((Id)ar.get('Id')).Potential__c = (Decimal)ar.get('sumMax');
        }
        update quotes.values();
    }
}
```

Finally, it should be said that nothing in this code should result in a "too many future calls" error, so presumably the problem lies with the test method itself.

### Edit

Updated code; I mistakenly used the "standard" quote object instead of the custom one.

Comment: @user4045 It's only 5am in the morning, but there you have it. I forgot you were using a custom object.

Comment: @user4045 Typo. Fixed it.

Comment: @user4045 The function name was misspelled in the class.

Comment: i am not getting value to the potential

Comment: code is running fine

Comment: hi @user4045, please be patient when adding comments. It may take other users some time to respond and they may not be in the same timezone as you. You may also need to add more detail to your comment, which explains what potential value you are expecting and the actual result.

Comment: the aggregate result which is calculating the potential value.it is not calculating

Comment: hi update the trigger

Answer (score 2):

Below query doesnt have Quote1__c field in it

```
 // Add Quote1__c  in the below query
for (Quote_line_item__c a : [Select Id, Name, IsFutureContext__c From Quote_line_item__c where ID IN :ID]) {
            a.IsFutureContext__c = true;
            if (a.Quote1__c != null){
                quoteIds.add(a.Quote1__c);
            }
```

I am surprised why you are not getting SOQL field reference without querying error.

Comment: super ,i got this now it is working

Comment: i am getting exception while deploying can you sort it

Comment: What is the exception ?

Comment: i had a photocopy pasted in the post check it out'

Comment: Can you paste the test class?

Comment: while deploying i am getting that error

Comment: @istest
public class quotepotentaialtest{
  static testmethod void unittest(){
list<Quote_line_item__C> quo=new list<Quote_line_item__C>();
batch__c b=[select quote_line_item__c from batch__c limit 1];
if(b.quote_line_item__c!=null){
 Quote_Line_Item__c quotelineitem=new Quote_Line_Item__c();   
    quotelineitem.id=b.quote_line_item__c;
    quo.add(quotelineitem);
        update quo;
        }
}
}

Comment: @user4045 See my answer, maybe it will help you sort things out. Also note that your test method should be explicitly creating new records instead of querying from the database. This is bound to cause problems.

Comment: The problem is you have many insert update operation running on Quote_Line_Item__c  object in same methods try to split the code into multiple methods where each method is free from GL